# Setting up Postgres: Can't connect remotely to Postgres server (debian)

Tags: postgresql, debian

I am having problem with connect with database from outside server. I read a lot of topics about of this subject. And nothing...

Postgresql 8.4 / Debian

My /etc/postgresql/8.4/main/**postgresql.conf**:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432
max_connections = 100
```

My /etc/postgresql/8.4/main/**pg_hba.conf**:

```
local all all trust
host all all 127.0.0.1/32 trust
host all all ::1/128 trust
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust
```

**netstat -nlp | grep 5432**

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN    6520/postgres
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN    6520/postgres
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     15338180 6520/postgres       /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

**telnet localhost 5432**

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.localdomain.
```

But when I try connect from my computer I always get "Failed to establish a connection to".

Any idea what I am doing wrong ? :/ Thanks for yours help :)

Comment: Perhaps it is a problem related with the IPv6, try to connect remotly by adding explicitly the ipv4 addrese of the server using `-h`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you disable the firewall on the server on which postgres is running?
If not, disable and test. If you are able to connect after the firewall is disabled, you need to open the port 5432 in your firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Check the obvious like IPTABLES, ensure this is not running:

```
iptables -L
```

http://wiki.debian.org/iptables

If it's running and the default rules are in place, then this could cause issues.